# why using copy two times in dockerfile?

Tags: javascript, dockerfile, config

I am trying to create a `Dockerfile`, then run with `docker-compose.yml`

I have my `Dockerfile` as below

```
FROM node:12


WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package*.json", "./"]
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

CMD yarn develop
```

it works perfectly fine, what I am wondering is, why do I need to run COPY two times in order to work? When I got it working watching some tutorials, then come back to the file trying to understand the commands more.  I figured there's 2 `COPY`, I thought I typed it by accident so I removed the second `COPY . .` but then I figured, if I do this, build again, then `docker-compose up` will not work anymore.  I need to keep the second `COPY . .`

What is the reason to this though?

Thanks in advance for the help to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will execute `npm install` only when package.json changes. That is the **good practice**.

But if you replace `COPY ["package*.json", "./"]` by `COPY . .` and remove bottom `COPY . .`. Then, this will execute `npm install` whenever you do a code change in **src** files. That is a **bad practice**.

Comment: ah ok, so the `COPY []` is actually different meaning than `COPY . .`  the first one just means copy `package*.json` to `./`  the second one is copying the whole project.  Right? Also, why would having the first `COPY` being a good practice though?

Comment: Yes, you can find more info on this link. https://dev.to/dimitrisnl/comment/ah9f